# receiving error when inflating spinner layout

Tags: android

So I am trying to set a custom image for my spinner drop down. I have went to a few stackoverflow questions and they all seem to have the same solution to get it done. For some reason when I try it I get this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.plansly/com.example.plansly.planner}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class Spinner
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class Spinner
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.plansly:drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown with resource ID #0x7f07006d
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07006d
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:900)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5078)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:280)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:74)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:258)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:225)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:175)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:196)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>`

activity spinner is in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activityBackGroundColor"
    tools:context=".planner">
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="467dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown"
        >
    </Spinner>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ic_spinner_dropdown drawable file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="2.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="64dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/more_vert" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: the problem might be due to `more_vert drawable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the ic_spinner_dropdown drawable and that fixed the problem. 
from:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="2.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="64dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/more_vert" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="64dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/more_vert"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In other words delete the bitmap code and and set the drawable source in the item tag and use gravity to set the position of drop down image