# How to add spinner arrow to spinner background Android XML

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I have this background file for a spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item  android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
          <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item >
        <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|left" android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner_arrow" android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp" />
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

And the file ic_spinner_arrow.xml:

```
<vector android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="128dp"
    android:viewportHeight="128" android:viewportWidth="128"
    android:width="128dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ababb2"
        android:pathData="m128.004,0v128h-128z" android:strokeWidth="0"/>
</vector>
```

The application run perfectly if I eliminate this item:

```
<item >
    <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|left" android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner_arrow" android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp" />
</item>
```

But after adding it, I get this error:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class Spinner

Comment: [maybe it'll help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009393/receiving-error-when-inflating-spinner-layout)

Comment: Thank you hassan, it works. are you android programmer?

Comment: your welcome. yes I'm android developer

Comment: I am from Iran, if you wanna be in touch, please contact me.